# Manage buttons in ListView to show/hide a part

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-button

I have a `ListView` with `Button`'s. I want to hide the item that is visible when I click a `Button` from second item.

[image]

If I click the button "1" , I want to hide the blue "layout". I can manage the layouts if the click is made it the same item , but when I click a button from another item the layout´s are still visible. How can I manage to set the visibility for those items?

This is may code.
My LISTADAPTER

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String item = items.get(position);
    View v = null;
    if (convertView != null)
        v = convertView;
    else
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    TextView itemTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
    itemTV.setText(item);
final ImageView number1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.number1);

    final ImageView number2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.number2);

    final ImageView button1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final ImageView button2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final RelativeLayout blue = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.blue);
    final RelativeLayout green = (RelativeLayout) v
            .findViewById(R.id.green);
    blue.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
    green.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);



    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (on == 0) //show hide ---int on=0;
            {

                blue.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                green.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
                on = 1;

                Toast.makeText(context, "ImageButton clicked" + item,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                number1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CLICK" + item,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                number2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "ClICK" + item,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }// on equals 0
            else {
                on = 0;
                blue.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
                green.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            }

        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            blue.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            green.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "CLICK" + item,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            number2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "CLICK" + item,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

My ACTIVITY

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list );

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {



                    Toast.makeText( ListImageButton.this,
                            "List item clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add( "item1");
    items.add( "item2");
    items.add( "item3");
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter( this, items);
    lv.setAdapter( adapter );
}
```

Comment: Your question is to vague to get a straight answer(I'm referring to *but when i click a button from another item the layout´s are still visible*). Basically you'll need a custom adapter but without other details it's hard to recommend anything else. Maybe post your current adapter's code.

Comment: When you click the `1` button in a row do you want to:a) hide the blue layout for that row? b) hide all the blue layouts for all the rows? c) something else? What is the purpose of that `on` variable in the `getView` method.

Comment: Yes when I click the button 1 or 2 form row-item2 , I want to hide the layout that is visible below row-item1 , for eg.The ideea is that when I click a button to have only one sub-layout activ(if I click on button2 the green layout ,and if I click on button1 the blue layout) and hide the sub-layout from another item2.

Comment: If you can give more info about the data that you want to display in ListView, i would be able to suggest you accordingly.

Comment: I change my image , maybe you will understand now. @PareshMayani

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to show the blue or green part on a *single* row depending on the number button that gets clicked from a row. Try something like this:

```
// two fields in the adapter class
private int mBlueFlag = -1;
private int mGreenFlag = -1;


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String item = items.get(position);
    View v = null;
    if (convertView != null) {
        v = convertView;
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    } 
    TextView itemTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
    itemTV.setText(item);
    final ImageView number1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.number1);
    final ImageView number2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.number2);
    // I assume this are the buttons with 1 and 2 which show the green/blue row part
    final ImageView button1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final ImageView button2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final RelativeLayout blue = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.blue);
    final RelativeLayout green = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.green);
    if (mBlueFlag != -1 && mBlueFlag == position) {
    blue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
    blue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (mGreenFlag != -1 && mGreenFlag == position) {
    green.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        green.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {          
             mGreenFlag = position;
             mBlueFlag = -1;
         // set the other OnCLickListener
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             mBlueFlag = position;
         // set the other OnClickListeners
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the info in wich is based this list, and call notifityDataSetChanged(), wich will recreate the list.